# Visual studio 2022 Preview 2 : 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 Preview 2.

I am getting some error while doing git commit:

```
Pushing master
Hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
Hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
Hint: your next pull:
Hint: 
Hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge
Hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
Hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
Hint: 
Hint: You can replace "git config" with "git config --global" to set a default
Hint: preference for all repositories. You can also pass --rebase, --no-rebase,
Hint: or --ff-only on the command line to override the configured default per
Hint: invocation.
Git failed with a fatal error.
Git failed with a fatal error.
Need to specify how to reconcile divergent branches.
```

Next I try to run the `git config pull.ff only` at command prompt but I get the following error.

```
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How and where do run the `git config pull.ff only`?

Comment: Have you been able to run any other Git commands so far?

Comment: Yes, it has been working fine from Visual studio 2022, i have done commits sucdessfully.

I am using git which is integrated within Visual studio 2022.
I have not run any commands directly from command window. this is the first time i am using git command directly from command prompt.

The issue started happening, after i created readme file directly on the GitHub via browser

Comment: To strictly answer your question, in order to run that command, you need to ensure that Git is installed outside Visual Studio. However, it seems that you do not *need* to run this command and your problem is that you first need to pull the changes you made on GitHub into your local repository (either by merging or by rebasing). You should be able to do that from Visual Studio without using the command line.

Comment: pull is failing as well.

Comment: Hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.
Hint: You can do so by running one of the following commands sometime before
Hint: your next pull:
Hint: 
Hint:   git config pull.rebase false  # merge
Hint:   git config pull.rebase true   # rebase
Hint:   git config pull.ff only       # fast-forward only
................

Answer (score 0):

The error you posted shows that you do not have the 'git' executable in the PATH environment variable.

I would strongly recommend installing the native git client along with the Visual Studio and putting the executable in the path. You will be much more adaptable with git binary on the PATH environment variable.

The Git for Windows installer does it for you on the Windows system.

When you will have the 'git' binary on the PATH, you will be able to execute those commands from command line. You can also execute those commands from Git bash.